# printing pdf files with <cfprint>

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018, cfprint

I am running ColdFusion 2018 on Windows 2016 (IIS) and having a problem printing a PDF file that I created using `<cfdocument>`. The printer is visible in CFAdmin and I can `<cfdump>` it. Here is what I've done:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Printing PDF</title>
</head>
<body>

<cfdocument format="PDF" name="3099274.pdf">
<cfoutput>

.... HTML is here ...

</cfoutput>
</cfdocument>

<cfprint type="pdf" source="3099274.pdf" printer="HP LaserJet 4345 CS">

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Check permissions. On Windows, the user running ColdFusions needs the `PRINTER_ACCESS_USE` permission. Also check ColdFusion's `print.log` for details about the print result. [See docs.](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfprint.html)

Comment: When I run the code, nothing happens at all. I called CF support and after an hour of looking around and trying different things we're back to square one. Support engineer said he will try to reproduce it on his PC to see if it's a bug.

Comment: @epipko - Then try the things Alex suggested above, i.e. Checking the permissions of the user account the CF Service is running under - and - check the various logs - `print.log`, windows event log (if applicable) for more info or errors.